# In Appium on Mac, how to clear cookies for a native mobile app, programatically?

Tags: cookies, automation, appium, session-cookies

I just build Login Test case for a native mobile app on iOS using Appium.

On first run, when test cases logs in the user. it does not clear the cookies.
when I re-run the test, it installs the app but keeps the user logged in. I need to clear cookies after all tests run. I kept below in after class but:

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies() is not supported
```

how should I clear all cookies?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reset the application to it's base state, consider resetting the app at the each session start.

```
capabilities.setCapability("fullReset","true");
```

More information on fullReset can be found in https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/reset-strategies/index.html

Comment: This uninstalls the App. I just wanted the user to get Logout